# Mongo client in Node doesn't receive connection response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, networking

I currently have a set of nodejs modules (containers) that connect to a local mongodb (also a container).
All modules works perfectly but with one of the I have the following problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuFqw.png

The connection seems to be accepted by mongo but the client doesn't receive the response and keeps waiting until it times out after 30 second (watch timestamps in the log)

The code of the client is the following:

```
async function connectToMongo() {
    try {
        const mongoUrl = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/LocalDB'
        let result = await MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
        logger.info("Connected to Mongo DB")
        return result
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error("Cannot connect to Mongo - " + err)
        throw err
    }
}
```

And is exactly the same as the other modules (that works).
Mongo is started without any settings or authentication.

I have tried using the following hostnames:

- mongo : name of the container in which mongo is running
- host.docker.internal : to address the host since the 27017 port of the container is binded to the host port

I honestly don't know what to try anymore...does anybody have an idea about what could be the problem?

UPDATE: as requested i'm adding info about how i'm starting the containers. Anyway I have omitted this part because they are started as Azure IoT Edge Modules. Anyway here is the infos from the deployment template:

```
"modules": {
          "mongo": {
            "settings": {
              "image": "mongodb:0.0.1-replset-noauth",
              "createOptions": "{\"HostConfig\":
{\"PortBindings\":{\"27017/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"27017\"}]}}}"
            },
            "type": "docker",
            "version": "1.0",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always"
          },
          "healthcheck": {
            "settings": {
              "image": "${MODULES.HealthCheck.debug}",
              "createOptions": {
                "HostConfig": {
                  "PortBindings": {
                    "9229/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "9233"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "type": "docker",
            "version": "1.0",
            "env": {
              "MONGO_CONTAINER_NAME": {
                "value": "mongo"
              },
              "MONGO_SERVER_PORT": {
                "value": "27017"
              },
              "DB_NAME": {
                "value": "LocalDB"
              }
            },
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always"
          }
        },
```

While this is the configuration of another module that perfectly works:

```
"shovel": {
            "settings": {
              "image": "${MODULES.Shovel.debug}",
              "createOptions": {
                "HostConfig": {
                  "PortBindings": {
                    "9229/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "9229"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "type": "docker",
            "version": "1.0",
            "env": {
              "MONGO_CONTAINER_NAME": {
                "value": "mongo"
              },
              "MONGO_SERVER_PORT": {
                "value": "27017"
              },
              "DB_NAME": {
                "value": "LocalDB"
              }
            },
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always"
          },
```

(it's basically the same)

The modules are currently being launched using the IoT Simulator or on an IoT Edge device as Single Device deployments.

Comment: How are you starting the containers; can you edit the question to include the `docker run` command(s) or `docker-compose.yml` file?  What code writes out a URL?  Do you get the `Cannot connect to Mongo` error you show in the code, and if so, can you also edit the question to include the error message?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @DavidMaze. I added the required informations to the question but as you can see I'm not using standard docker commands, anyway from the configuration file you can easly understand how the containers are run even without knowing Azure IoT Edge